# How to add default imports for generated unit tests in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

While generation unit test for java class Idea adds default static import

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

I want to extend this section by some more imports but I haven't managed to find a place where to configure them.

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1 Ultimate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are able to edit it through getting to:
 Settings -> Editor -> File and Code Templates -> Junit4 Test Class